# Intellisense in SSMS 2012 not working for 2008 server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms, intellisense

I did most of the solutions provided [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/).

I know about

- enabling IntelliSense
- clearing the cache
- connecting to a server >= *SQL Server 2008*
- using the latest SQL Server Service Pack

and it works locally with the *SQL Server 2012* engine.

But it still does not work when connecting to a *SQL Server 2008 SP1* engine from my *SSMS 2012*. If I do

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
```

I get `10.0.2573.0` as result. So the server is 2008 SP1.

### Edit

After a few days it started working. I don't know why.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2012 is the only environment that supports SQL Server Intellisense.  Have you tried a server side trace to see if the Intellisense session is getting errors?

Comment: @MaxVernon Intellisense has been in SSMS since 2008. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934481(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for pointing that out Shawn.  Clearly I'm wrong about it not being supported in 2008.  Still, a server side trace should allow the OP to see what is happening/not happening with Intellisense, right?

Comment: @MaxVernon and how do you do that? I have a problem with SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1617) and SSMS 2012 - IntelliSense not working...

Answer (score 1):

Try patching your server. I attempted to recreate your issue with SSMS 2012 (11.0.3000) by  connecting to four servers: one SQL Server 2008 (10.0.1600) and three SQL Server 2008 SP 1 (10.0.2531). As you can see the only difference between the four servers is one server does not have Service Pack 1  installed. On all of the servers with service pack 1 installed intellisence worked without issue. However, intellisence did not work on the server without service pack 1 installed.

You can download the service pack here.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20302

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if others are running into this issue still,  was surprised to run in to the issue as the setup at works was essentially a clean install.   Normally if/when there are errors like this it is more often older installs where you have installed multiple versions of SSMS and VS, and all associated Service and Security Patches...

Okay, long story short, what appears got intellisence was going into my specific login for and fixing up my user mapping to the database I wanted intellisence for.  I also tested after adding the "User Mapping" and getting the intellisence perfectly find for the DB, then removing my mapping, , and adding my user mapping back and having it work again...

So where intellisence  is not working for you start by adding an explicit "User Mapping" for you log-in to the database in question, seemed to work perfectly find for me.

Hope this helps others.

dan d:)